# 'ModelChoiceField' object is not iterable - calling objects from existing Model

Tags: python, django

Losing the will to live here lol - might be fairly obvious that I'm new to Django/Python.

Can't work out what's going wrong here, I'm calling objects from a model that has values in Django Admin but every time I try to fix one thing, it breaks another.

I want to be able to create a new entry from frontend, but I get this error when trying to migrate:

**Stack error**

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 784, in __init__
    self.choices = choices
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 801, in _set_choices
    value = list(value)
TypeError: 'ModelChoiceField' object is not iterable
```

Please see my model below:

**models.py**

```
# Model
engineer_shifts = [
    (0,'Shift 1'),
    (1,'Shift 2'),
    (2,'Shift 3')
]

class Engineer(models.Model):
    engineer = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="John Smith",verbose_name="Engineer")
    engineer_shift = models.IntegerField(choices=engineer_shifts,verbose_name="Shift")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.engineer}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Engineers'

class CreateHandoff(models.Model):
    handoff_pk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    handoff_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,verbose_name="Handoff Date")
    shift1_lead = models.IntegerField(choices=engineer_picker,verbose_name="Shift 1 Lead")
    shift1_sec = models.IntegerField(choices=engineer_picker,verbose_name="Shift 1 Secondary")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.handoff_date}"
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Handoffs'

# Form
engineer_picker = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Engineer.objects.all()
    )

class CreateHandoffForm(forms.ModelForm):
    shift1_lead = forms.ChoiceField(
        label = "Select Shift 1 Lead",
        choices = engineer_picker,
        required = True
    )

    shift1_sec = forms.ChoiceField(
        label = "Select Shift 1 Secondary",
        choices = engineer_picker,
        required = True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = CreateHandoff
        fields = ["shift1_lead","shift1_sec"]
```

Comment: At least, a quote is missing in your `engineer_shifts` definition, is it only in your post?

Comment: Hey @Christophe, indeed, I have corrected now - this was not missing from the code :)

Comment: What is `IntegerField(choices=engineer_picker,...)` supposed to do?

Comment: You should update the post too (and test again)

Comment: Why do you use IntegerField when you should use a ForeignKey for `shift1_lead` and `shift1_sec`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Not sure if it's the correct type, but it's supposed to save values to the model and the choices are inherited from Engineer model.

Comment: @IainShelvington I did try to use ForeignKey but I do not think it is the correct field representation, requires positional arguments: 'to' and 'on_delete' and this isn't something I need from this field.

Comment: @destinedtolearn: `to` is the `Engineer` model, and `on_delete=` is what should happen in case the `Engineer` you refer to is removed from the database...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you for the explanation! I have amended but I still get the error: TypeError: 'ModelChoiceField' object is not iterable

Comment: @destinedtolearn: that is because using `engineer_picker` as choices does not make any sense: that is a `ModelChoiceField`, not a list of choices...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a `ForeignKey`, you can make a `ForeignKey` to refer to a model record, so:

```
class CreateHandoff(models.Model):
    handoff_pk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    handoff_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,verbose_name="Handoff Date")
    shift1_lead = models.ForeignKey(Engineer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lead_handoffs', verbose_name='Shift 1 Lead')
    shift1_sec = models.ForeignKey(Engineer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sec_handoffs', verbose_name='Shift 1 Secondary')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.handoff_date}"
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Handoffs'
```

For the `ModelForm`, you do not need to specify the fields: Django will automatically make `ModelChoiceField` for these, so:

```
class CreateHandoffForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CreateHandoff
        fields = ['shift1_lead', 'shift1_sec']
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you a million times thank you! - I'm having issues now with the crispy form tags but I'll work it out hopefully ;)